# Adding a new class with Swift to an existing published Realm database

Tags: migration, realm

I have a published iOS app that is using a Realm database and I need to add a new class to the database and I need to preserve user data. Not sure how to proceed with the migration.

The Realm documents describe how to add a new variable with the migration code, but I am not sure how to add an entire class to the database.

I have also changed the main variable from var register:Results? To var register:List? And I am not sure if this needs to be migrated too.

I would appreciate any insights.

Thanks!

Blessings,
—Mark

Answer (score 2):

Since no one was able to help me, I finally discovered that adding another model/class does not require Migration. Only a change to the existing model will require Migration.

Changes in code do not need migration, but they DO change how the application will behave with data saved previously. I am still working on that!

Hope this helps others who are learning to use Realm.
Blessings,
—Mark